# Gridview Dynamic formatting according to conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have this code on RowDataBound that alternates the color of the cells and also add an onclick event on the cells. The data comes dynamically from a stored procedure so the gridview has only one control. The ButtonField.
I want to have white color for cells that  hasn’t any data inside, how can I achieve this?

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{


    {
        string back1 = "url('Images/GridBack1.jpg')";
        string back2 = "url('Images/GridBack2.jpg')";

        if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            TableCell Cell = e.Row.Cells[i];


            // if both row and column are odd, color them black
            // if both row and column are even, color them white
            if (((e.Row.RowIndex % 2 == 1) && (i % 2 == 1)) ||
                ((e.Row.RowIndex % 2 == 0) && (i % 2 == 0)))


            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[i].Text)) //Edit
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.Blue;
                    e.Row.Cells[i].ForeColor = Color.White;
                }
                else
                {

                    e.Row.Cells[i].Width = Unit.Pixel(450);
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Height = Unit.Pixel(67);
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-image", back1);
                    //e.Row.Cells[i].Style.Add("width", "150px");
                    //e.Row.Cells[i].Style.Add("word-wrap","break-word");
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("align", "center");
                }



            }
            else
            {

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[i].Text)) //Edit
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.Blue;
                    e.Row.Cells[i].ForeColor = Color.White;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Width = Unit.Pixel(450);
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Height = Unit.Pixel(67);
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-image", back2);
                    //e.Row.Cells[i].Style.Add("width", "150px");
                    //e.Row.Cells[i].Style.Add("word-wrap", "break-word");
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("align", "center");
                }


            }
        string color = "#000000";
        e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("Style", "background-color: " + color + ";");
        e.Row.Cells[0].Width = Unit.Pixel(150);
        e.Row.Cells[0].Height = Unit.Pixel(67);


    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton _singleClickButton = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
            string _jsSingle = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(_singleClickButton, "");
            // Add events to each editable cell
            for (int columnIndex = 2; columnIndex < e.Row.Cells.Count; columnIndex++)
            {
                // Add the column index as the event argument parameter
                string js = _jsSingle.Insert(_jsSingle.Length - 2, columnIndex.ToString());
                // Add this javascript to the onclick Attribute of the cell
                e.Row.Cells[columnIndex].Attributes["onclick"] = js;
                // Add a cursor style to the cells
                e.Row.Cells[columnIndex].Attributes["style"] += "cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;";
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to assign white color to the every cell and then overwrite according to conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` like

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[i].Text))
{
  e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.Blue;
  e.Row.Cells[i].ForeColor = Color.White;
}
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)

Hope it works.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me the context for 'when'. I take the error:the name 'when' does not exists in the current context

Comment: oho sorry i was thinking that you are using `foreach` loop,just use `if condition` instead of `when`, hope it works..

Comment: Nothing changed. The background is the same. I also tried to changed with your condition the backround image but with no luck.

Comment: debugg your code, this will work, i am using the same code to change the `color` of my empty `cells`..

Comment: what do you suggest? I put it before the if - else that change the background image

Comment: where u r trying to change the `color` of cells , Put my condition as well, means check for `empty` cells condition.

Comment: spoon feeding is always not gud, not try to solve your problem but try to learn as well.i am assign `MSDN` link,plz check it.

Comment: I checked it . I also i added the code to protected override void Render but still no luck.